# A generic way of applying interfaces to classes with the same properties

Tags: c#, moq, system.reflection

I have an interface with a bunch of `string` properties:

```
public interface INameable
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Surname { get; }
}
```

And a class that happens to have the same properties, without however implementing the interface. Let's assume that I don't have access to modify the class (i.e. that it is implemented in an external DLL):

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

I have written a generic class that, given an object of the external class, will return to me an instantiation of that interface with all the values of the object:

```
public T ExtractInterface<T>(object argument) where T : class
{
    var mock = new Mock<T>();
    foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        var returnValue = argument.GetType().GetProperties().SingleOrDefault(p => string.Equals(p.Name, property.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))?.GetValue(argument);

        ParameterExpression value = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "value");
        Expression setupProperty = Expression.Property(value, property.Name);
        var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(setupProperty, value);
        mock.Setup(func).Returns((string)returnValue);
    }
    return mock.Object;
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
var person = new Person { Name = "Joe", Surname = "Blogs" };
var personWithInterface = ExtractInterface<INameable>(person);
personWithInterface.Name.Dump();
personWithInterface.Surname.Dump();
```

The problem with this is that it only works with `string` properties. Can someone please help me modify the method so that it works with properties returning any type?

Comment: Hello @Philip could you tell us what you want to achieve by doing this? 
What have you already tried ? For example it would be valuable for you to get the type of the `returnValue` and use the appropriate Expression to adjust the return type ? Is the Expression that will adjust the type what you are looking ? Also Where would you use that?

Answer (score 1):

This would be much easier, even if you have to do it over and over. Unlike using reflection, you won't get a runtime error if the class and the interface no longer match by coincidence. It just won't compile.

```
public class PersonWrapper : INameable
{
    private readonly Person _person;
    public PersonWrapper(Person person)
    {
        _person = person ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(person));
    }

    public string Name => _person.Name;
    public string Surname => _person.Surname;
}
```

If you do something "generic" with reflection, this will compile:

```
var list = new List<string>();
INameable person = ExtractInterface<INameable>(list);
```

Unless we have absolutely no choice, anything that "tricks" the compiler so that we can compile things that shouldn't compile is a recipe for trouble. It takes away one of the most powerful tools we have to prevent runtime errors.

---

This is essentially the same approach used to "adapt" `HttpContext` to `HttpContextBase`, `HttpRequest` to `HttpRequestBase`, etc., except that those are abstract classes instead of interfaces.

The original implementations didn't implement an interface or inherit from an abstract class, but it later became apparent that it would be helpful if there were abstractions (using the term loosely) for those classes.

So they created new abstract classes with exactly the same properties as the original classes, just as you created new interfaces for some existing classes.

They didn't use reflection to map the existing classes to the abstract classes. They just did used [a wrapper](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/Abstractions/HttpContextWrapper.cs) which behaves just like the code above.